# run .jar file on a machine which does not have jdk or jre

Tags: java, jar

I want to run .jar file on a machine which does not have jdk or jre. Is it possible, if yes then how?
I tried to run my .jar file on a machine which does not have jdk or jre, it fails.

Comment: you want to run jar without jdk or jre ..??

Answer (score 1):

I can assure you that you **will need** a [JVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) at some point. A JVM is included in either the JDK or JRE. (JDK is needed for development).
Whether that [JVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) is pre-installed or bundled with your executable is up to you.

You may want to check [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) project as an example. There are many other java "wrappers" like this.

Answer (score 0):

The **JRE** software package is needed to **use java application** while **JDK** software package is needed to **create java application**. So

JDK ---> programmer and software developer

JRE ---> common everyday user.

Some jdk include jre.

Thank you.

Comment: OP knows what are JDK and JRE. The question is something else, so technically this is not answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Jar is just archive with .class files. You can't run .jar file on machine which doesn't have jre, because jre executes .jar .